# do...while loop iterates once too many, while loop iterates once too few - php

Tags: php, html, mysql, while-loop, do-while

I have been building photo galleries for many of my own and client websites for some time now. They are MySQL database-driven, I use MySQLi extension with PHP, and the galleries have a 'Gallery' page and a 'Thumbnails' page with a jQuery lightbox used to serve up the final image once a thumbnail is clicked. I have at least half a dozen such galleries on my server alone, and with each new one, I start with the code base of the last gallery I built.

The "Gallery" page in every one of my existing galleries uses a do...while loop to display all the galleries in the database (usually paginated) after the results are selected with a prepared statement. In EVERY case, the do...while loop runs through the selected records and displays the data without a hitch.

Then I started a new gallery today and developed a problem out of nowhere. I say it this way because I have used code from one of my other site galleries and that one works perfectly.

DETAILS:
The `galleries` table in the new database has 7 columns, one of which is `type` and that column contains either the word 'photo' or 'video'. For testing there are 5 dummy galleries in the database, 3 photo and 2 video. The default setting for the page is to select all records, unless either of the "Photos" or "Videos" links are clicked, in which case they pass a query string and a different select query is used to select and display only photo or video galleries.

The query code (which works as desired):

```
if (($gType != 'photo') && ($gType != 'video')) {
    $getGalleries = "SELECT gallery_id, gallery_type, gallery_thumb, gallery_part, gallery_name, gallery_about
    FROM galleries
    WHERE gallery_live = ?";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($getGalleries);
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $live);
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $type, $thumb, $part, $name, $about);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->fetch;
} else {
    $getGalleries = "SELECT gallery_id, gallery_type, gallery_thumb, gallery_part, gallery_name, gallery_about
    FROM galleries
    WHERE gallery_type = ?
    AND gallery_live =?";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($getGalleries);
    $stmt->bind_param('si', $gType, $live);
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $type, $thumb, $part, $name, $about);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->fetch();
}
```

And the HTML/PHP with the do...while loop:

```
<?php
do {
?>

<div class="galleries">
<div class="thumb_<?php echo $type; ?>">
<img src="graphics/<?php echo $type; ?>.jpg">
</div><!-- .thumb_photo / _video -->

<p class="about_title">
<?php echo $name; ?>
</p>

<p class="about_text">
<?php echo $about; ?>
</p>
</div><!-- .galleries -->

<?php       
} while ($stmt->fetch());
?>
```

I put a sample page up [HERE](http://xoverr.net/test/sample2/index.php) to show the problem I am having.

So opening the page displays all contents of the `galleries` table, 5 galleries total. But this time using a do...while loop as I have in every other gallery, the do...while loop iterates one too many times, leaving an empty `<div>` and a missing `.jpg` image at the top then the 5 galleries are displayed below it. When either the "Photo" or "Video" links are clicked, the page reloads and shows the correct galleries and NOTHING extra. Clicking the "All" link reopens the page, all 5 galleries and the extra `<div>` at the top. When I change the loop to a while loop, the default page is now free of the extra `<div>` which is great...but when either the "Photo" or "Video" links are clicked, they serve up one fewer record each.

I have been headscratching this one all day. It's not as though I have never done this before, yet lo and behold, I now have this mysterious problem.

Again, I've used this technique many times, so I have to be missing something simple. Any help will be sincerely appreciated. Thanks!

**UPDATE:**
I forgot to mention one item. Out of frustration, I added a query to count the number of entries in the database, and it came up with 5. This led me to think the queries were not the issue, rather that is was, somehow in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue might just be that you have

```
$stmt->fetch;
```

inside of your `if (($gType != 'photo') && ($gType != 'video')) {` block,

Where you should have

```
$stmt->fetch();
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue you are having is due to the conditional for your else in your php file.

i.e.

```
else {
$getGalleries = "SELECT gallery_id, gallery_type, gallery_thumb, gallery_part, gallery_name, gallery_about
FROM galleries
WHERE gallery_type = ?
AND gallery_live =?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($getGalleries);
$stmt->bind_param('si', $gType, $live);
$stmt->bind_result($id, $type, $thumb, $part, $name, $about);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->fetch();
}
```

In the above code, your basically telling the parser, "Even if the if fails, still fetch and make another div in the HTML."

The last "fetch" will probably take care of your issue.

Hope this helps!